# Optimizing algorithms for multiple queries of the same kind

Tags: algorithm, search, optimization

There is a particular class of algorithm coding problems which require us to evaluate multiple queries which can be of two kind :

1. Perform search over a range of data
2. Update the data over a given range

One example which I've been recently working on is this(though not the only one) : [Quadrant Queries](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/quadrant-queries)

Now, to optimize my algorithm, I have had one idea :
I can use dynamic programming to keep the search results for a particular range, and generate data for other ranges as required.

For example, if I have to calculate sum of numbers in an array from index 4 to 7, I can already keep sum of elements upto 4 and sum of elements upto 7 which is easy and then I'll just need the difference of the two + 4th element which is O(1). But this raises another problem : During the update operation, I'll have to update my stored search data for all the elements following the updated element. This seems to be inefficient, though I did not try it practically.

Someone suggested me that I can combine subsequent update operations using some special data structure.(Actually read it on some forum).

**Question:** *Is there a known way to optimize these kind of problems? Is there a special data structure that does it? The idea I mentioned;Is it possible that it might be more efficient than direct approach? Should I try it out?*

Comment: Look into segment trees and binary indexed trees.

Comment: My answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065238 might help explain the difference between segment trees and binary indexed trees.  Briefly, to update a range you want to use segment trees with lazy update.

Comment: I have used BIT before, so I think it will work in this particular one. But, if the operation is multiplication rather than addition, using BIT is a little hefty. I am gonna check out segment trees.

Answer (score 1):

It might help:
[Segment Trees](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=pl&tl=en&u=http://was.zaa.mimuw.edu.pl/?q=node/9&sandbox=0&usg=ALkJrhjyuj-twyqJnP_KP9IJubrIGkx81g) (Range-Range part)

Comment: Okay! Segment Trees seem to work for me! I don't see if it is the most efficient, but definitely more efficient than what I had.